# Use eyeray trigger to speak with NPC in Unity3D for Vive

Tags: unity, 3d, htc-vive

I'm developing a first-person-player game in Unity for HTC Vive. Basically, I want my NPC to speak when my player looks at him for more than a second. I didn't find any eyeray tutorials to achieve this for Vive. Please help.

Comment: Does it have to be specifically eye tracking, or does it trigger if the NPC is simply in the center of the player's field of view?

Comment: @tyjkenn no, doesn't have to be specifically eye tracking, just make sure the NPC is at the center of the view, as there are multiple NPCs present. i'm also trying this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aJhPm5h1pl4) out, as a starting point, so suggestions still welcome.